# Reading array of text elements without quotes

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

Have a pandas dataframe with records looking like below :

```
 0 [/computers_&_electronics,/computers_&_electronics/electronics_&_electrical,/computers_&_electronics/electronics_&_electrical/data_sheets_&_electronics_reference,/shopping,/shopping/consumer_resources,/shopping/consumer_resources/coupons_&_discount_offers]
 1 [/sports,/sports/college_sports,/sports/sporting_goods,/sports/sporting_goods/basketball_equipment,/sports/team_sports,/sports/team_sports/basketball]
 2 [/business_&_industrial,/business_&_industrial/advertising_&_marketing,/business_&_industrial/advertising_&_marketing/sales,/law_&_government,/law_&_government/legal,/law_&_government/legal/product_liability,/shopping,/shopping/consumer_resources]
```

I want to read each hierarchy (e.g : /sport/college) as an array element and then perform operations.But since there are no quotes present in the hierarchy ( ideally should have been  '/sport/college', ... ) each record is being read as one big string.

I tried with `literal_eval` but didn't work.Any other pointers ? There are about 7 million records on which the array conversion needs to be performed so looking for a fast and scalable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `[]` and then `split`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
```

Comment: @raul - What is `print (df['col'].head().to_list())` ?

Comment: Never mind it does work ,The only warning i obtain while performing is : /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:22: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead